# Regex for validating options for select entered by users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

I am developing a Rails 3 application which contains several forms that include dropdown selects. The options shown in the selects shall be configurable for the admins of the application.

Admins can enter the options in a text area. Each new line in the text area defines the content to be shown in the select.

```
A - Option 1
B - Option 2
C - Option 3
```

The tricky part now comes with validating what the admins enter in the options. 
Each option line should follow a certain pattern where the first part (before the hyphen) is the key for the option and the second part (after the hyphen) is some explanation.

I am currently using the following regex to validate each line:

```
(.+) *- *(.+)
```

Now I want to validate multiple lines at the same time.
The example above should be valid while the following should be invalid:

Example 1:

```
A - Option 1
B - Option 2
C
```

Example 2:

```
A - Option 1
B - Option 2
  - Option 3
```

I have added delimiters in the regex to match on lines (i.e.: (^(.+) *- *(.+)$)+ ), but it is not working as expected.

Comment: Very Good and well formatted question (*+1*)...

Answer (score 0):

Using `/\A(^\w+ *- *\w.+\n)+\z/` as regular expression.

```
def validate(options)
  options =~ /\A(^\w+ *- *\w.+\n)+\z/
end
```

Examples:

```
validate(<<EOF)
A - Option 1
B - Option 2
C - Option 3
EOF
# => 0
```

---

```
validate(<<EOF)
A - Option 1
B - Option 2
C
EOF
# => nil

validate(<<EOF)
A - Option 1
B - Option 2
  - Option 3
EOF
# => nil

validate(<<EOF)
  - Option 1
B - Option 2
C - Option 3
EOF
# => nil

validate(<<EOF)
A -
B - Option 2
C - Option 3
EOF
# => nil

validate(<<EOF)
EOF
# => nil
```